# Where can I find a catalogue of error messages for the standard packages in Python?

Tags: python, documentation

I am referring to Errors like

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

which happen when you

```
>>> a_dictionary = {}
>>> a_dictionary.update([[1]])
```

Is there a place where these Errors for standard packages like dictionaries are documented?

An online research didn't yield any results.

*Edit: I am not asking for Exception types, but rather the specific error messages. There can be for example different messages for ValueErrors, I am looking for a catalog of those error messages.

Comment: Are you asking about just the exception type (in this case `ValueError`), or the specific error text?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

Comment: A single place for documenting all possible error messages for the exceptions doesn't seem feasible. I don't think you'll find a catalogue anywhere. Not to mention asking for off-site resources is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why, I am looking for additional documentation hints. I think this should be part of the python documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think all errors are subclasses of the Exception class. Thus, the following code will list them for you:

```
def get_all_subclasses(cls):
    all_subclasses = []

    for subclass in cls.__subclasses__():
        all_subclasses.append(subclass)
        all_subclasses.extend(get_all_subclasses(subclass))

    return all_subclasses

errors = get_all_subclasses(Exception)
print(errors)
```